# date not formatting correctly on a date that does not exist

Tags: vb.net, validation, date, format

I have the following code to convert a date (from a database entry) into the correct format:

```
Dim blah As Date = "02/29/2001"
MsgBox(Format(blah, "yyyy-MM-dd"))
```

However, it keeps telling me this:

**Conversion from string "02/29/2001" to type 'Date' is not valid.**

Now i see that 2/29/2001 does not have a day 29- only 28 for that year. So how would i check for this so it doesn't throw an error when a date in the database table is not entered correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `IsDate()`

This function returns true if your string or date can be converted to date.

like this

```
Dim dateAndTime As String
dateAndTime = "March 15, 1981 10:22 AM"
noDate = "Hello"
dateCheck = IsDate(dateAndTime)
dateCheck = IsDate(noDate)
```

This will return true for the first one and false for the second one

Also, this function works with month of 29, 30 or 31 days like in your case

[here's](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/00wf8zk9%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) the msdn link

Answer (score 2):

You could use `TryParseExact` instead, so something like:

```
Dim enUS As New CultureInfo("en-US") 
Dim dateString As String 
Dim blah As Date 

' Parse date with no style flags.
dateString = "02/29/2001"
If Date.TryParseExact(dateString, "MM/dd/yyyy", enUS, DateTimeStyles.None, dateValue) Then
   MsgBox(Format(blah, "yyyy-MM-dd"))

Else
   MsgBox(String.Format("'{0}' is not in an acceptable format.", dateString))
End If
```